# Django Edit Form Creates New Instance

Tags: python, django

I am creating a form that allows users to edit an event saved to a django database. The problem is when it runs the code, a new instance is created in the database, the old one remains in the database and both are then available to view in the site

Below is (some of) the HTML form that is used to call the edit view and edit the instance in the database

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
        <form action="edit/" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="event_edit_id" id="event_edit_id">
          <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Next, is the View that is used to edit the event for the id sent with the form:

```
def edit(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    event_id = int(request.POST.get('event_edit_id'))
    event = Events.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    form = AddEventForm(request.POST or None, instance=event)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('calendar')
```

I know I am missing something but I just can't see it, any help appreciated!

**EDIT**
I've noticed that when the code is submitted for edit, it goes straight to /calendar/ instead of /calendar/edit so this is the urls file I use to map the files

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.calendar, name="calendar"),
path('delete/', views.delete, name="delete"),
path('edit/', views.edit, name="edit"),
]
```

Comment: Try printing the result of the event query. There seem to be no reference to `event_id` in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your form, I can only guess that there's nothing populating `edit_event_id`, so the form is saved as a new event. Currently, `edit_event_id` isn't a bound field, so it doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Good point, but I populate the event id with jquery, if I make that input visible it does show up, I use the same idea for my delete method and it works perfectly..

$('#event_edit_id').val(event.id);


Even when I hard code the event ID in views.py it doesn't edit...

Comment: So is `AddEventForm` a `ModelForm`? Does it have a field called `edit_event_id`? 
What's the value of `request.POST`?

Comment: thanks for your help Rob, pointed me in the right direction to find my error :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got it, and it was impossible for anyone else to get it because the issue was further up in the code than in the I had included in the html.

My error was that I had not changed the code properly after a previous edit. There was another form that was open and I didn't delete the start of the form tag..

Basically, I didn't make sure the HTML tags each had an opening and closing tag.

On this is correct, the code above will work to edit entries :)